# Adobe illustrator COM library could not find font

Tags: c#, com, adobe-illustrator

I'm creating an application for adobe illustrator. It puts some label on picture. 
Here is the code:

```
        TextFrame frame = page.Layers["textLayer"].TextFrames.Add();
        frame .Contents = "Test";
        frame .TextRange.CharacterAttributes.TextFont = _illustratorApp.TextFonts.GetFontByName("Arial Black");
        frame .TextRange.CharacterAttributes.Size = 48;
```

It works, but illustrator can't find font by name and it looks like this:

[image]

And the looks like

[image]

If I set it mannualy it looks ok. What am I doing wrong?

P.S. If I set font mannualy it's name is the same